# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host returns a string of numbers

Tags: iis, url

I have a website that emails a link to the invoice when an order is complete.

The link should be http://mysite.com/QuoteAndBook/Confirmation?orderId=123

But for some reason it is:

http://204435-204435/QuoteAndBook/Confirmation?orderId=123

The host portion of the link is generated using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host but I would expect that to return "mysite.com", not "204435-204435".

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the IT guy was changing something with the server configuration and broke it. Not sure what he did but he's fixed it now...